# dart, overloading [] operator?

Tags: operator-overloading, dart

Is it possible to overload the index`[]` syntax for a collection/iterable type? for example I am writing a `SortedList<T>` class that wraps around a standard `List<T>`. and I'd just like to pass on the usage from my sorted list straight down to the underlying list object. I thought I'd read about this on the dart language tour but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Dart editor seems pretty happy with:

```
operator [](int i) => list[i]; // get
operator []=(int i, int value) => _list[i] = value; // set
```

Try it in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ee693897fd84488525e9)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can *override* operators. Like this:

```
T operator [](int index) => items[index];
```

But you can't *overload* anything in dart. Because Dart does not support operator or function overloading. That means your class can't have two function with same name but different parameters.